# xpath+ regex: matches text

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to write an xpath such that only nodes with text with numbers alone will be returned.
I wanted to use regex and was hoping this would work

```
td[matches(text(),'[\d.]')]
```

Can anyone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here

```
<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>a</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

seams that you are missing quantification, `[\d.]` will match only 1 character, so 1 should be selected, 10 on the other site requires something like `+`, so try your regex like:
`td[matches(text(),'\d+')]`

Also that `.` in regex will make it capture non-digit characters, do not add that one.

You can test all your regex queries on [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: `.` will match any character except line breaks. So `10` will be also selected. But you are right, it is better to use `+` in this case

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov: Should not as its enclosed in square brackets, it will select only 1 character of given set of characters and meta characters in it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK so far Selenium support XPath 1.0 only, so `matches()` is not supported.

You can try below instead:

```
//td[number(.) >= 0 or number(.) < 0]
```

To match table cells with integers

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
td[matches(text(),'[\d+]')]
```

with:

```
td[matches(text(),'\d+')]
```

***Note:*** regex works only in `xPath 2.0`