# How to get <p> that contains text which matches regex

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this [website](http://alfie.tokyo/schedule/201811.html) using scrapy, xpath and regex.
I have checked and tried the answers to this question:
[xpath+ regex: matches text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368762/xpath-regex-matches-text)

I want to create a 'scrapy.selector.unified.SelectorList' of `<p>` that contain the text "11 (sun)" or "9 (fri)" and such, and loop through the list.

```
event = response.xpath('//p[matches(text(), "\d+\s\(\w{3}\)")]').extract()
```

does not work.

FYI, below does work.

```
event = response.xpath('//p[contains(text(), "11 (sun)")]').extract()
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `matches(text(), ".*[0-9] \([a-zA-Z]{3}\).*")`

Comment: Thanks, but not working for me and gets the error as below.

ValueError: XPath error: Unregistered function in //p[matches(text(), ".*\d+\s\([a-zA-Z]{3}\).
*")]

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047567/xpathevalerror-unregistered-function-for-matches-in-lxml), it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only after text, Karan Verma's answer is sufficient.

If you're after the elements themselves, keep reading.

`matches` is only available in XPath 2.0 and higher (as are the other regex functions), and is not available in scrapy.

Scrapy uses parsel for parsing, which in turn uses lxml, which only supports XPath 1.0.
It does, however, support [regular expressions in the EXSLT namespace](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath)

Since the regex namespace is enabled by default in scrapy, you can do this:

```
event = response.xpath('//p[re:match(text(), "\d+\s\(\w{3}\)")]')
```

Comment: Thank you stranac for the answer. This seems the answer I was looking for, but it returns empty list. Regex seems not matching the text I'm targeting. If I use ".*" it returns all potential <p>. Any advice on the regex to grab 11 (sun), 12 (mon), 13 (tue) and such? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong with the scrapy shell url, forgot to include $(date + %Y%m) to get YYYYMM strings in the path. It worked just fine. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re()` instead of `extract()`
Call the .re() method for each element in this list and return their results flattened, as a list of unicode strings.
.re() returns a list of unicode strings. So you can’t construct nested .re() calls.

`event = response.xpath('//p/text()').extract("\d+\s\(\w{3}\)")`

**Note**: re()  decode HTML entities (except < and &).

For more information please refer doc here : https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.re

Comment: Thanks for the input, but like stranac mentioned, I am after the elements 'scrapy.selector.unified.SelectorList'. I've modified my question.